# VBA Outlook - Run automatically for all email in inbox?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have the following code which I am using to save an email attachment into a folder. I want to make this vba run automatically each time I open outlook and check all emails in my creditchecks@hewden.co.uk inbox (non default inbox).

At the moment though it only checks the email which is selected in the active inbox. can someone please show me how I can edit my code to get it to do what I need. thanks

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    Dim strDeletedFiles As String
    Dim withParts As String
    Dim withoutParts As String


        ' Get the path to your My Documents folder
        On Error Resume Next

        ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
        Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        ' Get the collection of selected objects.
        Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    ' The attachment folder needs to exist
    ' You can change this to another folder name of your choice


        ' Set the Attachment folder.
        strFolderPath = "\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\"

        ' Check each selected item for attachments.

        For Each objMsg In objSelection

        Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
        lngCount = objAttachments.Count
        If lngCount > 0 Then

        ' Use a count down loop for removing items
        ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
        ' confused and only every other item is removed.

        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

        ' Get the file name.
        strFile = objAttachments.item(i).FileName
        If Right(strFile, 3) = "pdf" Then

        ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
        withParts = strFile
        withoutParts = Replace(withParts, ".pdf", "")

        strFile = strFolderPath & withoutParts & "\" & strFile

        ' Save the attachment as a file.
        objAttachments.item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

    End If
        Next i
        End If


        Next

    ExitSub:

    Set objAttachments = Nothing
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set objSelection = Nothing
    Set objOL = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: You want it to check **all** mails, or just all **new** mail?  For new mail, perhaps consider calling this procedure (with some modifications) from the `Application_NewMailEx` event. For dealing with multiple inboxes, check [this](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/handling-multiple-inboxes/) or use Google. If you get stuck, revise your Q. The answers are out there ready to be found and we can help you if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to edit some lines. Use something like `objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("credutchecks@hewden.co.uk")` to a folder in the same level of your Inbox folder. Here is your code modified:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    Dim strDeletedFiles As String
    Dim withParts As String
    Dim withoutParts As String


        ' Get the path to your My Documents folder
        On Error Resume Next

        ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
        Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        ' Get the collection of selected objects.
        'Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        'Istead set this to the selected objects you just need to set to your email folder

        'This is for a inbox same level folder
        Set objSelection = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("credutchecks@hewden.co.uk")

        'This is for a folder inside the inbox folder
        'Set objSelection = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("credutchecks@hewden.co.uk")

    ' The attachment folder needs to exist
    ' You can change this to another folder name of your choice


        ' Set the Attachment folder.
        strFolderPath = "\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\"

        ' Check each selected item for attachments.

        For Each objMsg In objSelection

        Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
        lngCount = objAttachments.Count
        If lngCount > 0 Then

        ' Use a count down loop for removing items
        ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
        ' confused and only every other item is removed.

        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

        ' Get the file name.
        strFile = objAttachments.item(i).FileName
        If Right(strFile, 3) = "pdf" Then

        ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
        withParts = strFile
        withoutParts = Replace(withParts, ".pdf", "")

        strFile = strFolderPath & withoutParts & "\" & strFile

        ' Save the attachment as a file.
        objAttachments.item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

    End If
        Next i
        End If


        Next

    ExitSub:

    Set objAttachments = Nothing
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set objSelection = Nothing
    Set objOL = Nothing
    End Sub
```

To run it automatically when the Outlook starts just put it on the 'ThisOutlookSession' in the objects folder and name it 'Sub Application_Startup()'. Don't forget to enable macros before.

Comment: hi I have tried this but when I try and run it nothing happens, and my attachments wont get saved

Comment: You want only to sabe PDF attachments? Where your folder is located? Inside the Inbox folder or in the same level of it? What is your folder name? With this i can edit it better.

Comment: @RomeurForte this is my folder path, but the folder where the pdf is saved will be the name of the pdf attachment strFolderPath = "\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\ATTACHMENTS\"

Comment: What is your email folder where the emails are located?